# Run application in external server using PHP

Tags: php, windows, linux, networking

Am using windows server for running website. My application is running in linux server. I want to call the application with parameters(inputs) from website using php. The application accepts some inputs and returns output. I want to display the output in website. Please some one help me by giving idea or scripts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From your simplistic description, you might be able to use this on the windows webserver to invoke the application part residing on the linux server:

```
<?php
    readfile("http://otherserver.com/app.php?input=123");
?>
```

If the inputs are expected via POST, then you'll have to utilize [`cURL`](http://php.net/cURL) instead. (Which you'd have to do in case of a disabled `allow_url_fopen` anyway.)

Comment: That is not a php application it is a running software.

Comment: Be sure to mention such things in the question, and not two hours later. Also: `ssh2_exec`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WinExe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/) in your Linux system and execute command from your PHP to remotely call command lines on your Windows system

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you please tell me briefly? Can u gimme ur mail ID?

Comment: Well from where to where you want to send request...is it from Windows you want to send request to Linux...or the other way

Comment: Install OpenSSH in Windows and execute it from PHP like "ssh user@host command"